# Ownership automatically changed in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm experiencing a strange behavior in Snowflake and couldn't find any explanation in the documentation.

```
use role accountadmin ;
use database some_database;
create schema test_schema;
drop schema test_schema;
```

Result:

```
SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'TEST_SCHEMA'
```

When I check the schemas with show schemas I find that the ownership of TEST_SCHEMA belongs to another role.

Snowflake documentation only says that the ownership of an object is set to the role which created it, and the only way to have it owned by another role is transfer of ownership.

I've tried granting usage on future schema to accountadmin, but it hasn't fixed the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: We will need more context. Is this repeatable?

Comment: Has the database got future grants set up on it?

Comment: @NickW please post it as the answer. So others can see this one is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database probably has future grants set up on it that automatically assigns ownership of each new schema created

Comment: how can I check that please, SHOW GRANTS ON DATABASE shows only current grants

Comment: SHOW FUTURE GRANTS IN DATABASE { <database_name> }

Answer (score 1):

To revoke grants on future schemas I ran the following:

```
revoke ownership on future schemas in database <database> from role <role>
```

Note that this won't revoke ownership on existing schemas